# With recursion and threads, how to avoid "Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow. Thread 0x00007d54"?

Tags: python, multithreading, recursion

I am fetching product structure information from an API which returns given a product number as input, which subproducts it consists of. The maximum depth of a product tree is 13 levels but the total number of products inside a structure can be 10 000 - 20 000 procuts.

```
                           root
                sub 1  ---^   ^---- sub 2
     sub 1.1 --^ ^--sub 1.2   sub 2.1 -^ ^- sub 2.2
   ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ... ... ... ... ... ...
```

I have set up a recursive solution that can create the full structure.
The API takes quite some time to generate the result and I have therefore decided to use concurrent.futures for threading.

Since the root product can have between 10 000 -> 20 000 subproducts I will make in total 10 000 -> 20 000 recursive calls to the function `product_consists_of`.

I have set up the solution as follows

`main.py`

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
   output_list = []
   product_list = read_excel_function() #Function that reads excel with all products to breakdown ~10000
   with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
            future_to_products = {executor.submit(product_consists_of,product,output_list): prod for prod in product_list}
            for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_products):
                try:
                    dummy = future.result()
                except Exception as e:
                    log_file.write(traceback.format_exc())
                    raise e
   list_to_json_blob(output_list) #Function for transforming the list to a json_blob to be consumed by NoSQL.
```

`structure.py`

```
def product_consists_of(product_name,output_list)
   meta_data = fetch_meta_data(product_name) #Function that makes 1 API call to return meta data
   output_list.extend([(product_name,meta_data)])
   ... # some more functions
   subproducts_xml = fetch_product_xml(product_name) #Function that makes 1 API call to return structure data
   subproducts = parse_xml(subproducts_xml) #Function that
   for subproduct in subproducts:
       product_consists_of(product_name,output_list)
```

When a product has no subproducts, it will not enter the for loop.

After running my script for a few hours I got `"Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow. Thread 0x00007d54"`.

After searching here on SO it seems that it has to do with my recursive function using up to much memory, in combination with threading. I am not to familiar with threading and am wondering if I am doing something wrong here. Since the deepest level of recursion should be 13 levels, I can't see how I have reached the maximum level of recursion depth which is 1000?

- Am I supposed to terminate the threads at some point?
- Does it count the total number of recursive calls per thread? Because a chain of recursion calls should not be deeper than 13 at any point in time, and not have more than 4 threads at the same time. Meaning that I believe that the maximum number of recursive calls at any point < 4*13 = 56

Comment: Threads probably don't have anything to do with it, but you've got a recursion problem *somewhere*. It sounds like you're recursing a lot deeper than you think you are.

Comment: I'm keeping track and the deepest chain is no deeper than 13 levels, so the depth is not the problem. But a single thread will be able to make around 10 000 recursive calls in total, just that at any given point in time, the recursive chain is not deeper than 13.